# Unable to save reports to PowerBI Report Server - Create with Recent Version

Tags: powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have been struggling to upload reports created with PowerBI Desktop to our PowerBi Report server.

It continually tells me:
[image]

"We're not able to upload this report. The report was created with a recent version of Power BI Desktop that is not yet supported by this server."

I have researched online and the most common advice I find is to make sure that the PowerBI Report Server is the most recent version and to be sure you are using the proper version of PowerBI desktop for this. I have done that, to no avail.

PowerBI Report Server:
[image]

PowerBI Desktop:
[image]

I have tried both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the desktop client.

I am using a version of Power BI Desktop that is optimized for use with PowerBI Report Server.

[image]

I am not sure what else to try.  I cannot save from the client, nor can I upload via the browser. I do have *one* report that I have been able to upload via the browser. It was an old report (from 2020) that I found on my computer. It uploaded and seems to work fine, but I have no idea what version of PowerBI Desktop it was created in, and when I try to open it and save it in the new version of PowerBI Desktop, it fails.